# What does useContext really do?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming

I'm quite hooked by React but one big question arises to me regarding useContext. It's quite confusing to really know how it's inner workings are.. Like it magically works.

**So I have in my main module this:**

```
export const Context = React.createContext(SOMEVALUE) // why set this initial value here

const [value, setValue] = useState(SOMEVALUE) // why set this here again?

return(
<Context.Provider value={[value, setValue]}> // why do i have to pass this  inital value here?
<App />
</Context.Provider>
)
```

**Next some module inside**

```
import { Context } from './Main' // why import this when everything was passed?

...

const [value, setValue] = useContext(Context.offline) // what does this help?
```

---

Now here come's my question:

Why is importing the Context from Main required, and how does React make a connection to the state using this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**- What is the value passed into `createContext` for?**

```
export const Context = React.createContext(SOMEVALUE)
```

The value passed in to `React.createContext` is a fallback value which will ONLY be used if a `Context.Consumer` is used outside of its `Context.Provider`. This is different than an initial value.

**- Why is the same fallback value being used in `useState`?**

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(SOMEVALUE)
```

Using the same value as an initial value and a fallback value is preference and will change based on the use case. This piece is actually setting an initial value, and providing a mechanism to both keep track of and change that value.

**- Why do I have to pass the initial value to `Context.Provider`?**

```
<Context.Provider value={[value, setValue]}>
```

The `Context.Provider` acts like the publisher in a publisher/subscriber system. It's going to broadcast these values set here to any of the matching `Context.Consumers`. It does not keep track of the value or provide mechanisms for changing that tracked state. `useState` from above does that. `Context.Provider` is just "broadcasting" the value and the function to change that value.

**- Why do I have to import the `Context` I created?**

```
import { Context } from './Main'

const [ value, setValue ] = useContext(Context)
```

`import { Context }` is importing the `Context` object you created and exported from `'./Main'`. The same `Context` object you're using to render the `Provider`. This is used to make sure the right `Provider` is referenced when subscribing.

Prior to hooks, you would subscribe to a react context via: `static contextType = MyContext` in a class, or with `<MyContext.Consumer>`. [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) is just another api for doing this as a hook. You have to pass it a `Context` object so it knows which `Context.Provider` to subscribe to since there can be any number of them.

Documentation for Context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a very complete answer. But I still don't know how ``` import {Context } ``` makes any connection to the Context in the upper class. Otherwise I think I got it.

Comment: No problem. `import { Context }` is importing the `Context` object you created and exported from `'./Main'`. The same `Context` object you're using to render the `Provider` first code snippet. I'll update the answer.

Comment: But importing that Context will just create a new context.. I mean the state is no longer the same? Its basically just a copied function. I could also create a context with the same name inside the second file and it would result likewise?

Comment: In the first file you're creating the Context and using its Provider. In the second file all you're doing is using that Context object as a reference. It's finding the Provider from that Context object and subscribing to it.

Comment: This explains everything. Thank you all.